# What would lead to copy_X in sklearn linear models to be overwritten?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

On the [documentation for Linear Regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression), the following is provided:

```
copy_X : boolean, optional, default True
If True, X will be copied; else, it may be overwritten.
```

RAM is limited for me and I would prefer setting `copy_X = False`, what scenario will there be in which my `X` will be overwritten and is there a flag to see if that happened to warn me to reload the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you set the `copy_X` option to False, you are given a new copy as long as the dimension of your scipy sparse matrix is not equal to the dimension after passing the logic on the method `_ensure_sparse_format`  on line [371](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/utils/validation.py#L371). Plus, scipy astype method by default creates a copy (i.e. the `astype` [method](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/01d8bfb6f239df4ce70c799b9b485b53733c9911/scipy/sparse/data.py#L68-L77))

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Scipy, so I didn't follow your answer. I'm sending a numpy array to it, why would it convert it to a sparse matrix? And moreover, why would the dimensions of the sparse matrix be any different? Lastly, I did not see that high of a spike in RAM when I set `copy_X=False`, why would that be if it would by default create a copy?

Comment: hi @Al-BaraaEl-Hag, in your case, your matrix is not a sparse matrix right?

Comment: if you follow the source code, this might be the case when you give a sparse matrix

Comment: Yeah, my matrix isn't sparse. Would that mean that I can set `copy_X=True` without worrying about it?

Comment: that's what I could explain and the source code says, yes.